Replace zircote/swagger-php GET parameters array with one referenced schema
I have GET request annotation, something like this:
//
\OpenApi\Attributes\Get(
    path: '/api/v1/todos',
    parameters: [
        // here my long parameter lists
        \OpenApi\Attributes\Parameter(name: 'name', in: 'query', schema: new \OpenApi\Attributes\Schema(type: 'string')),
        // ...
        \OpenApi\Attributes\Parameter(name: 'surname', in: 'query', schema: new \OpenApi\Attributes\Schema(type: 'string')),
    ],
),
//

Is there a way to move whole parameters list into one referenced schema?
I use Laravel 8 and trying to move long annotation's parameters content from my controller into the controller's request.
